# How do I get the current input split being processed by the UDF in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In typical MR Jobs, this is achieved by 
    ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit).getPath()

Answer (score 0):

You can only access this from a loader. Check out the source for [PigStorage](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.java?view=markup), specifically the prepareToRead method.